# Spreading Props TypeScript with React and Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I seem to be having troubles spreading the props in a component that uses StyledComponents under the hood. Whenever I try to pass a prop not defined in the interface (a style tag, for instance), I get an error.
Here´s my current implementation:

```
interface IParagraphProps {
  text: string;
}

const StyledParagraph = styled.p`
  max-width: 90%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
`;



const Paragraph = (props: IParagraphProps) => {
  const { text, ...rest } = props;
  return  (
    <StyledParagraph {...rest}>{text}</StyledParagraph>
  ) 
};
export default Paragraph;
```

EDIT: Here´s the error:  `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IParagraphProps'.`
And the place where I use this component:

```
const Card = () => {
  return (
        <Paragraph
            style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}
          text="whatever"
        />)
```

};

Comment: Where is your error happening ? Inside of this component or in another component calling this one? I don't have an error with just this component

Comment: Another component using this one.Example:  <div> <Paragraph style=/> </div>

Comment: Can you provide the calling code ?

Comment: Edited the answer with the calling code.

Comment: Its because the Paragraph function accepts the props as IParagraphProps type and that doesn't have any definition of ```style```. In your Card component, you are setting style as one of the props of Paragraph which doesn't exist on its definition ie IParagraphProps

Answer (score 4):

You're giving a style property to your Paragraph component, however this component only expect a text property. You should either remove that property:

```
const Card = () => {
  return (
        <Paragraph
          text="whatever"
        />)
};
```

or you should add the property to your component:

```
interface IParagraphProps {
  text: string;
  style: React.CSSProperties;
}
```

If you want to match whole the possible props you can do something like that:

```
type IParagraphProps =  {
  text: string;
} & React.ComponentProps<typeof StyledParagraph>
```

Comment: Yes, but I´m looking to spread the props. For instance, if I want to pass a tabIndex to it, it doesn´t make sense to declare it in the interface. Or if I had a Button, to declare both a disabled and onClick prop....

Comment: Edited. I don't know if there's a way to make it work with an interface though

Comment: Thanks for the edit! How would it work without an interface, if I may ask?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, here i used a type so I'm not using an interface

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the first answer but using an interface instead of a type:

> If you want to match whole the possible props you can do something like that:
>
> type IParagraphProps =  {
> text: string;
> } & React.ComponentProps

If you want to be able to spread any props other than text to the StyledParagraph, you need to specify in the IParagraphProps interface that it can accept any of the props for the StyledParagraph.

```
interface IParagraphProps extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof StyledParagraph> {
  text: string
}
```

^^^ Now the props for this component are specified as `text: string` + every prop that StyledParagraph accepts. If you want to allow a ref as well you can change ComponentPropsWithoutRef to ComponentPropsWithRef and use [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Source: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/basic_type_example/#useful-react-prop-type-examples